# What does (1) mean when declaring a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, syntax

What does the `...(1)` do?

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> tight_contour(1);
```

Comment: See constructor #3: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: it initializes the outer vector with a single element.

Comment: **Moderator note**: There are some who appear to be enforcing some "minimal effort" standard (which doesn't exist) by closing and deleting this question. On Stack Overflow, the proper standard is [mre] and, since this is a basic syntax question, *it meets that*. If this question is a duplicate, close it as such. Otherwise, this is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tight_contour` is a `std::vector` object containing elements of type `std::vector<cv::Point>`.  The `(1)` is constructing `tight_contour` to hold 1 initial default-constructed element.

Answer (score 0):

That `(1)` is simply saying that `tight_contour` should be initialized with one element in it.